# Invalid argument supplied for foreach while loading functions through an array

Tags: php, arrays, oop, foreach

I got the following code into my application:

```
    public function generate_function_list($generated){
        foreach($generated as $method){
            call_user_func($method);
        }
    }
    public function echotest($text){    
        echo '<p>' . $text . '</p>';
    }
```

And I execute it like this:

```
    $arrayx = array(
        FormGenerator::echotest("test container 1"),
        FormGenerator::echotest("test container 2"),
        FormGenerator::echotest("test container 3"),
        FormGenerator::echotest("test container 4")
    );

    $nez->generate_function_list($arrayx);
```

This is the output:

```
<p>testcontainer 1</p><p>testcontainer 2</p><p>testcontainer 3</p><p>testcontainer4</p>
```

Yes, as you can see the output is correct, it executes the function and its params correctly, but unfortunately I get this below:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\AppServ\www\test\testclassgenerator.php on line 2

I've been checking for the foreach within the generate_function_list function, and I see that I can't read the functions being set inside, so it's a bit strange.

My intention is to call methods dinamically, using a simply array, and giving the timely params.

Thanks!

Comment: foreach expects an ARRAY. If you get 'invalid argument', then you're passing in something that ISN'T an array, like a string or a number. So do a `var_dump($generated)` inside your method and see exactly what did get passed in.

Comment: What I get is this: { [0]=> NULL [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL [3]=> NULL }. All params seems to be reached, because they all are being executed in the output, even if you see NULL values out there.

Comment: so your echotest is doing output, and not returning anything which'd be captured in the array definition. which'd mean you're doing `call_user_func(null)`, which will never work. and the actual foreach producing this error is occuring elsewhere, since you ARE passing an array of nulls in the generate_function_list.

Comment: Hello @MarcB, so then why it returns a correct output?

Comment: because `$foo = echo 'bar'` doesn't assign anything to `$foo`. echo is not a function, it has no return value. It does some output, and then `$foo` becomes null. So your array is properly full of null. You call your echo test, it does some output, and then returns nothing, meaning php puts null into the array.

Answer (score 0):

An example of why your array building is incorrect:

```
function foo() {
   echo 'foo'; // immediate output of 'foo', no return value
}

function bar() {
   return 'bar'; // no output, return 'bar' to the calling context
}


$foo = foo();
$bar = bar();

var_dump($foo); // outputs: NULL
var_dump($bar); // outputs: string(3) "bar"

$array = array(
    foo(),
    bar()
);

var_dump($array);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> NULL
  [1]=> string(3) "bar"
}
```

Your `echotest` performs output. It has no `return` call. A function which has no `return` gets assigned the `NULL` value by PHP when execution returns to the calling context.

So your array, exactly as you stated in your dump output, is an array of NULLs, one for each echotest() call you made inside the array. You then pass that array to your `generate_function_list()`, which will simply iterate over all those nulls, and do a series of `call_user_func(NULL)` calls, which is pointless.